# TextArea ignore KeyEvent in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Java,JavaFX
As in tittle, how can i force TextArea to ignore KeyEvent,and make sth instead of this KeyEvent. I should rather say that I would like to overwrite method which append a character from KeyEvent.

Fo example: If i click 'k' on keyboard in the TextArea i would like it to be printed in console (not appended to TextArea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend, try this:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, e -> {
    if (e.getCharacter().equals("k")) {
        e.consume();
    }
});
```

or:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
    if (e.getCharacter().equals("k")) {
        e.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Where should i put it? if i try to put it in my java class which controll fxml file it doeasnt recognize method setOnKeyTyped.

Comment: i try this in initialize method, but it still write 'k' :)

Comment: BUT WIth KEY_PRESSED insted of KEY_TYPED runs correctly.THX