# How do I stop TextArea from listening to Shortcut KeyCombinations as KeyEvents?

Tags: javafx, shortcut, keyevent

Just as the title says, how do I stop shortcut keys (accelerators) being picked up as key events in TextArea? I have tried the method suggested here with different modifications: [TextArea ignore KeyEvent in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370439/textarea-ignore-keyevent-in-javafx) with no luck.

Comment: Which accelerators are you trying to ignore? The accelerators of the `Scene` or things like `Ctrl+C` that is defined on the `TextInputControl` itself?

Comment: Slaw, I'm trying to ignore Ctrl + S, Ctrl + O and the like. I've spent hours trying to find a solution that doesn't include removing the accelerators :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop specific accelerators from working when the `TextArea` has focus simply add an event filter for `KEY_PRESSED` events.

```
public class AcceleratorFilter implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

  // blacklist of KeyCombinations
  private final Set<KeyCombination> combinations;

  public AcceleratorFilter(KeyCombination... combinations) {
    this.combinations = Set.of(combinations);
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(Event event) {
    if (combinations.stream().anyMatch(combo -> combo.match(event)) {
      event.consume();
    }
  }

}
```

```
TextArea area = new TextArea();
area.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new AcceleratorFilter(
  KeyCombination.valueOf("shortcut+o"),
  KeyCombination.valueOf("shortcut+s") // etc...
));
```

If you want to indiscriminately block all accelerators registered with the `Scene` then you can query the `Scene`s accelerators and consume the `KeyEvent` if appropriate.

```
TextArea area = new TextArea();
area.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
  var scene = ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene();
  // #getAccelerators() = ObservableMap<KeyCombination, Runnable>
  var combos = scene.getAccelerators().keySet();
  if (combos.stream().anyMatch(combo -> combo.match(event)) {
    event.consume();
  }
});
```

This latter option may cause issues if you're not careful. For instance, if you have a default `Button` in the `Scene` then the above event filter may interfere with the `ENTER` key. Also, this option won't necessarily stop things like `shortcut+c`, `shortcut+v`, etc. because those shortcuts are registered with the `TextInputControl`, not the `Scene`.